# Shortcut for Find Next in Project

Tags: xcode, shortcut

I'm using Find in Project (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>) a lot, but having to click on each result is cumbersome. I know there is <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to jump to the next find result in the currently open file.

Is there a shortcut to jump to the next find result in the Find Navigator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear so. If you open up the Preferences and click on "Key Bindings", you can see all the possible menu commands and set keys for them. In the "Find" menu section, there is no command for "Find Next in Workspace", only the regular "Find Next".

Comment: In recent versions of XCode, there is now a "Find Next in Workspace" key binding.
The default is set to `^⌘G` (control + command + g).

Answer (score 1):

You can always hit <kbd>⇥</kbd> (tab) once (changes focus into the results, although there's no visual indicator) and then <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> keys to move between the results.